# Burning a USB Windows Recovery drive to DVD

Tags: boot, images, bootable-media

I have a USB Windows Recovery drive for Surface 2, which is an ARM device running Windows 8.1 RT. I need to recycle the USB, so I thought of copying out the Recovery. So in PowerISO, I copied the contents files-wise & saved it into an image. Done.

It'll also be nice if I can also burn the image as a bootable DVD. Problem now is, in PowerISO, which do boot information do I add (Action > Boot > Add Boot Information)?

I've looked around the contents & found a few candidates:

> /efi/microsoft/boot/BCD
>
> /efi/boot/bootarm.efi
>
> /boot/boot.sdi

Which of them should I use? What I do know is that with the image I have now, to flash it back with Rufus to the USB drive, I need to enable GPT & UEFI for the drive to boot properly.

Comment: Try each one until you get it to boot, then answer your own question showing which one worked

Comment: That's basically one DVD sacrificed to the god of wastefulness. Then again, I could hit jackpot on the first try.

Comment: Or, I can virtualize in Hyper-V & mount the CD image when booting of Surface 2. I dunno.